# Python turn text file into dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a spell checking function and I have a text file that looks like this

```
teh the
cta cat
dgo dog
dya day
frmo from
memeber member
```

The incorrect spelling is on the left (which will be my key) and the correct spelling is on the right (my value).

```
def spell():
    corrections=open('autoCorrect.txt','r')
    dictCorrect={}
    for line in corrections:
        corrections[0]=[1]
        list(dictCorrect.items())
```

I know what I want my function to do but can't figure out how to execute it.

Comment: have you considered using an [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for this? If you built this you could see how close words are and you could set up a text file that just has all of the words. All you would do is pick the word that matches the best

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
with open('dictionary.txt') as f:
    d = dict(line.strip().split(None, 1) for line in f)
```

`d` is the dictionary.

**disclaimer:**
This will work for the simple structure you have illustrated above, for more complex file structures you will need to do much more complex parsing.

Comment: Ack! Beat me to it by mere seconds! (have a +1)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget that's all it takes :)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to get rid of the new line character?   {'teh': 'the\n', 'frmo': 'from\n', 'dgo': 'dog\n', 'cta': 'cat\n', 'memeber': 'member', 'dya': 'day\n'}

Comment: edited with a `strip()` no more newlines. (But the `split()` with `None` should take care of most white-space characters, strange that you still have new-lines)

Answer (score 0):

You problably want to use split to get the words, then map the misspelled word to the correctly spelled one:

```
def spell():
  dictCorrect={}
  with open('autoCorrect.txt','r') as corrections:        
    for line in corrections:
      wrong, right = line.split(' ')
      dictCorrect[wrong] = right
  return dictCorrect
```