# Python check for word in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a spell checking function and I'm using two text files: one that has misspelled text and a text file with a bunch of words from the dictionary. I have turned the text of misspelled words into a list of strings and the text file with dictionary words into a list of words. Now I need to see if the words in my misspelled list are in my list of dictionary words.

```
def spellCheck():
    checkFile=input('Enter file name: ')
    inFile=open(checkFile,'r')

# This separates my original text file into a list like this
# [['It','was','the','besst','of','times,'],
# ['it','was','teh','worst','of','times']]

    separate=[]
    for line in inFile:
        separate.append(line.split())

# This opens my list of words from the dictionary and 
# turns it into a list of the words.

    wordFile=open('words.txt','r')
    words=wordFile.read()
    wordList=(list(words.split()))
    wordFile.close()


# I need this newList to be a list of the correctly spelled words 
# in my separate[] list and if the word isn't spelled correctly 
# it will go into another if statement... 

    newList=[]
    for word in separate:
        if word in wordList:
            newList.append(word)
    return newList
```

Comment: I hope I fixed the indentation correctly - could you check? I had to juggle a few lines around...

Comment: Thank you! When I run my program I'm getting an empty list though. Do you know what I've done wrong?

Comment: Are you asking [this question again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681186/python-turn-text-file-into-dictionary) but now trying to use lists instead of a `dict`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
newList = []
for line in separate:
    for word in line:
        if word in wordList:
            newList.append(word)
return newList
```

The problem you had was that you were iterating over `separate`, which is a list of lists. There does not exist any list in your `wordList`, which is why that if-statement always fails. The words that you want to iterate over are in the sublists contained in `separate`. So, you can iterate over these words in a second for-loop. You can also use `for word in itertools.chain.from_iterable(separate)`.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

First, a word about data structures. Instead of `list`s, you should use `set`s, since you (apparently) only want a copy of each word. You can create sets out of your lists:

```
input_words = set(word for line in separate for word in line) # since it is a list of lists
correct_words = set(word_list)
```

Then, it is simple as that:

```
new_list = input_words.intersection(correct_words)
```

And if you want the incorrect words, you have another one liner:

```
incorrect = input_words.difference(correct_words)
```

Note that I used names_with_underscores, instead of CamelCase, as recommended in PEP 8.
Bear in mind, however, that this is not very efficient for spell checking, since you don't examine context.